# iPhone socket program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets

I want to create an extremely simple iPhone program that will open a telnet session on a lan-connected device and send a sequence of keystrokes. Most of the code I've seen for sockets is overwhelming and vast overkill for what I want to do:

1. open telnet socket to IP address
2. send ascii keystrokes

Any *simple* code examples out there I can play with?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd suggest you check out the [Asyncsocket project](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket):

It makes socket programming really easy; no messing with threads yourself and things happen asynchronously without much fuss.

I think there is a sample project with a client/server to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this will be helpful

Comment: how effective is this working with the 3g network?  im rather new to this, but ive noticed that my socket-based programs often work perfectly fine over wifi but fail over 3g, and im at a loss as to the underlying reason for this.

Comment: If you're trying to connect directly to the iPhone's ip addr, you may be thwarted by a firewall or NAT. If the iPhone is the client connecting to your server, could be just dropped packets/timeout. You should post a specific question with the details of your problem.

Comment: @AndrewPouliot Thanks.
Can you recoomend on the default timeouts for select operation on sockets in iphone?

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor: go read at least first 6 chapters of [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) Steven's book in which you can find plenty of simple examples and many advices how to avoid common pitfalls with network programming. Without doing that you will end with a buggy, slow and incomplete client.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this you will have to get basic idea of socket programming

http://ichuiphonedev.blogspot.in/2012/07/a-basic-idea-of-socket-programming-in.html

Answer (score 0):

i cant repost my code here, because SO considers it spamming to repeat your answer.

check out [this sample code and tutorial link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171570/1166727).  works like a charm and is really simple to implement, less than 3 minutes and you are up and going (IF you have a socket server ready).