# download file by listening to port

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I read a lot about socket programming in iphone application , but what I need help in , how to use certain port to download file from it and save it to certain directory in my application

any ideas, suggestion to implement that , I will send to the port binary stream represent the file (for example a.txt) how to receive it in my iphone application and save it

Answer (score 0):

See [iPhone TCP/IP Socket Server/Client Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437993/iphone-tcp-ip-socket-server-client-program)

Comment: May I ask , what if I want to convert the buffer that come to me to file again and save at the main bundle of my application

Comment: Ali, you cannot change the main bundle of the application once it's signed.  This prevent application from become malware after a user has installed it.