# Connecting from an iPhone client to a PHP server through sockets

Tags: php, iphone, sockets

In one of my projects a PHP server is successfully serving a php client via sockets but when I try an iPhone client using the NSStreams to this PHP server the client gets connected but if I send a string from the client to server, the xcode comes up with error message that connection is broken.

If I use the same iPhone client to connect to a server running on Python, it establishes the connection and strings are being read/written without any problem.

Can someone understand this please? If some sample or tutorial on PHP / iOS applications on sockets then I will be obliged.

Answer (score 2):

hi you can use WebSocketServer located on http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ and on Iphone clien http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-servert

Comment: Thanks for the reply, need to check on websockets on the php server side. However my research on this indicates that it is only supported on Chrome and limited support on few other browsers, so there may be platform support issues if one takes this approach. The client you mentioned, I have already imeplmented that one which is the one I mentioned that it works perfectly but only with the Python Server. A great article that one. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: This issue has been resolved, as I have replaced the Stream based client with raw-sockets and I am now able to connect and access the PHP socket server sockets from an iPhone socket client.

Answer (score 0):

i cant repost my code here, because SO considers it spamming to repeat your answer.

check out [this sample code and tutorial link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171570/1166727).  works like a charm and is really simple to implement, less than 3 minutes and you are up and going (IF you have a socket server ready).

as a general rule, php might not be the best solution for a socket server.  i like working with c++ or python better.  just holler if you need some sample code for a socket server using c++.

also, it is VERY VERY VERY important to check if your server has open ports.  unless you are using your own server, chances are that your hosting package does NOT open ports.  a virtual private server is necessary for that.  at this time, i strongly recommend amazon's AWS EC2 servers.

in case you have difficulties with it, i can give you a couple of nudges in the right direction.