# How to connect iPhone to Windows PC through IP address in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am doing one demo for connecting iPhone to Windows PC for sending files and text to PC from iOS Device. Can anyone give me a solution how can I approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start to study the socket connection. With a TCP connection you can send and receive data to / from PC.
Another way (to avoid the TCP connection) is to use UDP message: in this case you should write a UDP listener in your iOS App that listen incoming message on a specific udp port.

look at his link:
[iPhone TCP/IP Socket Server/Client Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437993/iphone-tcp-ip-socket-server-client-program)

Comment: Thank you but where I can learn about TCP/UDP listener program.I am new to iOS so I am unable to find TCP/UDP listener code for iOS.

Comment: Hi, but have you experience in Obj-c or Switf? If you look in the link, you can see a good start point to create a tcp connection.

Comment: Looking at this guide <http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html>

Comment: Hi the server is developed in Windows C#. net. So I want to connect that server through iOS device. So I am thinking that I have to connect through IP address. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes you have to know the IP address of the device. But if you want you can do this: From the PC you can send a broadcast message in the network using a UDP port. In the iOS, you can listen for incoming message in that particolar UDP port and send a reply when receive the message. When the PC receives the reply from the iOS device, it will know the iOS device IP automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81425/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-karthik-m).

Comment: Yeah right now I have an idea about that like take the port address and IP address of the PC statically but the problem was I am unable to underdstand that socket programming . I have already seen that which you have gave the tutorial but I didn't understand.

Comment: Right now I have port address and IP address and on PC the software is running which was developed in c#.net and it is listening which device is connected to it or not but I am unable to handle in iOS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81521/discussion-between-lorenzo-and-karthik-m).

Comment: Hi Lorenzo... How are you ??