# Telnet connection on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, telnet

I'm just wondering...

I've downloaded this App called "Telnet Lite" for the iPhone where you can connect to your devices through Telnet. You just give up the IP address, server port, username & password. Works great.

Now I'm wondering how this can be done (in code) on the iPhone. Can someone post a sample code where you establish a connection? I've seen aSynckSocket but I still don't know how to connect and where to give up the username & password for the device...?

Thanks!

Comment: very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083017/iphone-socket-program

Have you tried searching with google or something?

Comment: Yes I did Google. Came up with aSyncSocket. Did the basic stuff, established a connection but I need to give up the username & password for the device in order to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a socket framework/class/layer/whatever is only the first step. You need to review the Telnet RFCs -- there's a good list on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)) -- that will detail the protocol you'll need to implement on your (client) side.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way those clients work is to silently send up the username/password over the telnet connection when they detect the login prompt - then after that point you are shown what the server sends.