# Example socket programming in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, networking

I am learning objective C.I like to know about client/server(socket) programming for iphone.
I went through many answers,but still having many confusion with that flow and working.Can anyone help me out with code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone socket program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083017/iphone-socket-program)

Comment: i cant repost my code here, because SO considers it spamming to repeat your answer.

check out [this sample code and tutorial link][1].  works like a charm and is really simple to implement, less than 3 minutes and you are up and going (IF you have a socket server ready).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171570/1166727

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Using CoreFoundation's CFStreams](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI)

[Using raw sockets on the iPhone](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7815634)

Comment: Second link does not exists. Check it.

Comment: @chuck . These two links not exist as of now

Comment: The links do not work, please update them.

Comment: The links still don't work, please can you update them for us all to share.

Answer (score 3):

Go through this you will have to get  basic idea of socket programming

http://ichuiphonedev.blogspot.in/2012/07/a-basic-idea-of-socket-programming-in.html