# problem in saving a value in iphone

Tags: iphone

when i enter a value in the iphone simulator and press the save button it only keeps the value until the simulator is running. and when i restart the simulator and press the load button it shows an earlier value entered by me.i.e, it is not able to keep the new value and keeps only old value.

i am using following loops for saving a file and loading a file.

```
-(IBAction) save{

    NSUserDefaults *sinner=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [sinner setObject:serverIP.text forKey:@"load"];


    NSUserDefaults *king=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [king setObject:noc.text forKey:@"save"];

    }


-(IBAction) load {

    NSUserDefaults *sinner=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *tempstring =[sinner stringForKey:@"load"];


        serverIP.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:tempstring]; 



    NSUserDefaults *king=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *tempstring1 =[king stringForKey:@"save"];


    noc.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:tempstring1]; 




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Your code    
NSUserDefaults *king= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
[king setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"Bookmarks"];    
// saving it all  
[king synchronize];
```

Comment: @thanks buddy it worked.can u provide som help in socket programming.

Comment: See this: [Socket programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083017/iphone-socket-program). I don't have much of idea about this :)

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction) save{
NSUserDefaults *sinner=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[sinner setObject:serverIP.text forKey:@"load"];
[sinner setObject:noc.text forKey:@"save"];
[sinner synchronize];
}
```

This should save the contents. You dont need two separate userdefaults. To load them you can try

```
-(IBAction) load {
NSUserDefaults *sinner=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *tempstring =[sinner stringForKey:@"load"];
serverIP.text = tempstring; 
NSString *tempstring1 =[sinner stringForKey:@"save"];
noc.text = tempstring1; 
}
```

Hope this helps